# How do I subtract a time from another in c#?

Tags: c#, time

I've simplified my code down to this:

```
string when = "03/03/15 12:00 18:00";

string difference = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(when.Substring(when.Length - 5, 5)) - Convert.ToDateTime(when.Substring(when.Length - 10, 10))).substring(difference.Length - 5, 5);
```

But it's still very complex  **and**  also doesn't work :/

Basically I want the string  **difference**  to equal 6 because 18 - 12 is 6. It needs to be a little bit more complex because I want to evolve minutes too.

Am I being an idiot? Is it easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert your string to a couple of valid `DateTime` values, and subtract them.

The `Hours` property will give you a representation of the difference in whole hours, in this case 6.

```
string when = "03/03/15 12:00 18:00";

string[] portions = when.Split();  // 3 items: "03/03/15", "12:00", "18:00"

string yourDateTimeFormat = "MM/dd/yyHH:mm";  // or "dd/MM/yyHH:mm" if the day is first

// create a valid date from 03/03/15 and 12:00
DateTime fromTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    portions[0] + portions[1], yourDateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);

// create a valid date from 03/03/15 and 18:00
DateTime toTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    portions[0] + portions[2], yourDateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);

int differenceInHours = (toTime - fromTime).Hours;
```

Depending on how much control you have over the input, you may want to add additional logic for checking that the date is valid, or consider using `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Im kinda new to this and I'm getting two errors:
"The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context" and
"The name 'DateTimeStyles' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Sorry, but it's not recognising your line 6 as a correct dateTime

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/02eqj0vlc6odm39/Untitled.png?dl=0

I'm pretty sure it's correct (apart from the last lime, I've changed that).

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdvzbknpzjk7g9e/Untitled1.png?dl=0

Is that what you were after?

Comment: AH! yeah, I see you're in the USA. I've fixed the time but It still doesn't work. While I did need to change the day/month, that shouldn't have effected the example because 03 and 08 can be days or months.

Comment: Yeah, I have fixed "33:44" and the dateTime format but it still isn't working; it has the same error message. I have also tried `CurrentCulture` and `InvariantCulture`

Comment: `// create a valid date from 03/03/15 and 12:00
            DateTime fromTime = Convert.ToDateTime(portions[0] + " " + portions[1]);
            // create a valid date from 03/03/15 and 18:00
            DateTime toTime = Convert.ToDateTime(portions[0] + " " + portions[2]);
            TimeSpan differenceInHours = TimeSpan.FromHours((toTime - fromTime).Hours);
            Sunday.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(differenceInHours).Substring(0, 5));` 

That works, It's part yours and part mine. :)